# cpanel mailscanner+spam box

Tags: php, email, cpanel

We are moving over from ASSP Delux For cPanel to ConfigServer Mailscanner.
ASSP had too many issues, false positives, blocking legitimate emails, blocking commonly used IP's very easily and so on...

The 1 thing we would like to try and keep though is the spambox feature.
I know that the mailscanner can mark the email, or delete the email, but it does not move the email into a spambox folder, but I have found a link(below) which describes how to setup an individual account to move all spam marked to a folder in the inbox thus replicating the spambox folder.
http://support.hostrocket.com/knowledgebase.php?action=displayarticle&id=529

Is there anyway to automate this process?
Basically so when an email account is setup, it automatically creates the folder, and creates the rule which moves it to the folder?

I'm thinking maybe a cron as root that runs every couple of minutes or something of the like, but have not yet found any existing suggestions.

Thank you, any suggestions are welcome and appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you can really automate it. With cPanel the best approach si to create everything from the cPanel/WHM interface otherwise you might break things.

Basically if you follow that guide and do create a filter it will do this:
in the /home/cpaneluser/etc/domain.com/useremail it will create 2 files (filter + filter.yaml).

filter file contains this:

```
# Exim filter - auto-generated by cPanel.
#
# Do not manually edit this file; instead, use cPanel APIs to manipulate
# email filters. MANUAL CHANGES TO THIS FILE WILL BE OVERWRITTEN.
#

if not first_delivery and error_message then finish endif

#spam
if
 $header_subject: matches "^\\\\{Spam\\\\?\\\\}|^\\\\{Definitely Spam\\\\?\\\\}"
then
 save "$home/mail/domain.com/emailusername/.Junk/" 660
endif
```

the file filter.yaml looks like this:

```
---
filter:
  -
    actions:
      -
        action: save
        dest: $home/mail/domain.com/emailusername/.Junk
    filtername: spam
    rules:
      -
        match: matches
        opt: or
        part: "$header_subject:"
        val: "^\\{Spam\\?\\}|^\\{Definitely Spam\\?\\}"
    unescaped: 1
```

You might setup a cron that will check the existence of those files and if they are not there then it will create them. Not sure if they will be recognized by cPanel if you do create them manually via a cron script instead of creating them via cPanel interface.

Keep in mind that in the above example the filter was configured to move the Spam and Definitely Spam subjected messages into the Junk folder of the email address (which is automatically created by cPanel when you do create a new email address).